# How to add the record count at end of the file using awk

Tags: awk

I have file like below

```
H|ACCT|EXEC|1|TEMP|20130215035845|
849002|48|1208004|1
849007|28|1208004|1
855003|48|1208004|1
855004|28|1208004|1
855006|28|1208004|1
855008|28|1208004|1
855011|28|1208004|1
```

I want to add record count -1 (because first record is not the part of the hole records)
I need output as below

```
H|ACCT|XEC|1|TEMP|20130215035845|
849002|48|1208004|1
849007|28|1208004|1
855003|48|1208004|1
855004|28|1208004|1
855006|28|1208004|1
855008|28|1208004|1
855011|28|1208004|1
T|7
```

I tried below option `awk 'NF != 0 {++count} END {print count}`
But it is not writing at end of the file, how to calculate and add the result.

Comment: What you have will certainly print the record count to its output.  Do you want awk to write its output back to the input file?  That's a different question (which has been answered many times!)

Comment: Can't your write your trailer where the rest of the file is created? If you've already "lost" records by the time you do this, you just have a false sense of security by knowing how many records there are at this point in the processing.

Comment: `awk` doesn't have in-place editing capabilities. But then again, you really don't need `awk` to do want you want. Please see my answer. HTH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this line:

```
awk '1;END{print "T|"NR-1}' file
```

with your example:

```
kent$  echo "H|ACCT|EXEC|1|TEMP|20130215035845|
849002|48|1208004|1
849007|28|1208004|1
855003|48|1208004|1
855004|28|1208004|1
855006|28|1208004|1
855008|28|1208004|1
855011|28|1208004|1"| awk '1;END{print "T|"NR-1}'
H|ACCT|EXEC|1|TEMP|20130215035845|
849002|48|1208004|1
849007|28|1208004|1
855003|48|1208004|1
855004|28|1208004|1
855006|28|1208004|1
855008|28|1208004|1
855011|28|1208004|1
T|7
```

Answer (score 1):

### Use Built-In NR Variable

You don't need to use an explicit counter. You can use the built-in NR (number of records) variable. For example:

```
awk 'END { print NR-1 }' /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need `awk`. You can actually do this using coreutils and some nesting. You also avoid the need for temp files. Try:

```
echo "T|$(( $(wc -l < file) - 1 ))" >> file
```